# How is a Scene Node bound to MeshGeometryModel3D with HelixToolKit

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit, helix

I'm able to load in a model using assimp with:

```
SceneNode _sceneModel = new Importer().Load(path).Root;
```

This seems to load in the geometry into its separate meshes - for instance if in Maya you built a room with Wall_1, Wall_2, Wall_3, etc. the SceneNode is some kind of data structure with all the meshes.

The separate meshes can then be put into an array

```
        geometry = _sceneModel.Traverse().Where(x => (x is MeshNode)).Select(m => ((MeshNode)m).Geometry).ToArray();
```

But ultimately I just want to bind the entire single piece of geometry (eg a house) in xml to

```
<MeshGeometryModel3D>
```

but can't figure out how to do it. I can bind a single piece of geometry eg. from the geometry array I can bind geometry[1] which might represent a wall but can't workout how to bind the whole thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MeshGeometryModel3D is a wpf wrapper for Mesh Node (which is a scene node). If you only want to display your loaded model, you can add the root scene node into a GroupNodeModel3D.
You can find example here
https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/2254fce0870a165352ccb888e2f3e17398751724/Source/Examples/WPF.SharpDX/FileLoadDemo/MainViewModel.cs#L128

Comment: Thx. In xaml what is the difference between Element3DPresenter and MeshGeometryModel3D?

Comment: Element3DPresenter is just used to bind an element3d object in view model, like wpf presenter.